# How to change search engine in Nova launcher?

Tags: nova-launcher

All search bars in Nova Launcher use Google. Can I change this?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, remove the Google Search bar. After that, hold anywhere in the homescreen where there ins't any icons. Click "Widgets". Then browse to the widget of the search bar of your choice.

Comment: This answer is a workaround not a solution. I want to keep using the perstant browser as I can control transparency and how it looks, I cant do that with a widget.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to change the default browser of perstant search bar in Nova without removing it for a different widget.

1. Nova launcher > Home screen > search bar style > Nova search > search providers > add +
2. Url: search.brave.com/?q=%s
3. Move Google and Play store to disable providers by holding and dragging them down.

Now when you search, it will start searching for apps,but just keep trying and the last result will be the brave.search, hit enter, it will search brave.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answer, there is another way to change Nova Launcher's default search engine to use (although it is not very ideal unless you want to keep the Nova search widget).

To do it, disable all your search apps besides the one you want to use, and try to use the Search bar again.

It should give you the search app that you want to use.

I used it to switch from my default Search app (`com.android.quicksearchbox`) to Google Search.